# How to get foreign key from partial entity in Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I'm using Doctrine and Zend Framework 2. I don't know how to get a foreign key for the entity when I use a "[Doctrine partials](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html)". I also use a query builder and I want to return array.

Before I used: `IDENTITY(e.variable)` , but now when I use [partial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html) I have a code like: `partial e.{id, name...}`. And I don't know where and what should I use to get also foreign key.

If I will use `e.{id, name}, IDENTITY(e.variable)` then I get the foreign key but it is not a part of the same array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  'countryId' => string 'en' (length=2)
```

but I'd like to get:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      'countryId' => string 'en' (length=2)
```

I also know about `HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS` but this solution is for all foreign keys and then I can't decide which one I want to select or not, and I want to be more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have already solved the issue but I came from google searching for something similar and decided to share my experience.

To get flat rectangular data set just like you are using SQL, Doctrine suggests using partial objects. If you want to include the foreign keys too in the result set, just drop the partial syntax and list the columns directly:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, IDENTITY(e.country) as countryId FROM MyEntity e ...
```

Just make sure you use the `getArrayResult` method to retrieve your plain data array.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration

Answer (score 2):

Seems there are no way to do that, because according to http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#select-expressions 'partial' accepts only 'SimpleStateField'.

So have to join "Country c" and select "partial c.{id}".

Comment: This does what the questioner asked for. It creates a sub-array `country` with only one item `id`. Personally I think that `HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS` is faster because it saves some hydration.

Comment: Is there any way to select some fields without the partial and with and addSelect statement in a ManyToMany. THIS WORKS but include the primary key and don't let to use a IDENTITY(FK) => $qb->select('partial H.{id, name}')->from('App\Entity\Host', 'H')->leftJoin('H.clusters', 'C')->addSelect('partial C.{id, name}'); THIS DOESN'T WORK => $qb->select('H.name')->from('App\Entity\Host', 'H')->leftJoin('H.clusters', 'C')->addSelect('C.name');